# NodeJS Ajv module alway log message ' $ref: keywords ignored in schema at path "#" '

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, ajv

I'm using ajv to validate body request. With each one request come, ajv working is ok but it always log message ' **$ref: keywords ignored in schema at path "#"** '

I have 2 schemas, **login.json** & **login.defs.json**

**login.defs.json** to define a common schema definition and **login.json** refer to it.

**login.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "$id": "http://blog-js.com/login.schema#",
  "$ref": "login.defs#/definitions/login"
}
```

**login.defs.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://blog-js.com/login.defs#",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "login": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "account",
        "password"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "account": {
          "description": "The account or email of user",
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1,
          "maxLength": 255
        },
        "password": {
          "description": "The password of user",
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1,
          "maxLength": 32
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me what wrong I did ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you have the `additionalProperties` keyword set at the wrong place and Ajv is simply telling you about it.

You shouldn't see that message if that was the schema for `login.json`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://blog-js.com/login.schema#",
  "$ref": "login.defs#/definitions/login"
}
```

For `login.defs.json` that keyword should belong to the schema for `login`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://blog-js.com/login.defs#",
  "definitions": {
    "login": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "account",
        "password"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "account": {
          "description": "The account or email of user",
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1,
          "maxLength": 255
        },
        "password": {
          "description": "The password of user",
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1,
          "maxLength": 32
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's worked. But I think ajv's message is not clear. Thanks